# How could I do this code but with the output having a gap in between the Xs?

Tags: java, for-loop

How could I do this code but with the output having a gap in between the Xs?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class BlockMaker {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number.");
            int num = keyboard.nextInt();
            for(int x = 0; x < num; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < num; y++){
                System.out.print("X");
        }
            System.out.println();
            }keyboard.close();

        }
    }
```

The output, if I enter 5:

```
Enter a number.
5
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

So my desired output is:

```
Enter a number.
5
XXXXX
X   X
X   X
X   X
XXXXX
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to check if you're on the edge and print an X, otherwise a space:

```
if (x == 0 || x == num - 1 || y == 0 || y == num - 1) {
    System.out.print("X");
} else {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that it'd be cleaner to print the full row, then loop (but with 2 less iterations), then print another full row. Simple and understandable solution though.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson I thought so too, but quickly changed my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this works.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class BlockMaker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number.");
        int num = keyboard.nextInt();
        for(int x = 0; x < num; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < num; y++){
            if(x == 0 || x == (num - 1)){ // If we are the top or bottom row
                System.out.print("X");
            }else if(y == 0 || y == (num - 1)){  // If we are the first or last column
                System.out.print("X");
            else{ // Everything else print a space
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
    }
        System.out.println();
        }keyboard.close();

    }
}
```